# vimeo/player.js - Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular-components, vimeo-player

as stated in the title, I'm having some troubles trying to integrate [vimeo/player.js](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js) in my [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) application.

Since I haven't found any supporting library for angular 4, I'm following the steps in the **README.md** at *Using with a module bundler*.

I built **vimeo-player.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { Player } from '@vimeo/player';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-vimeo-video-player',
  templateUrl: './vimeo-player.component.html'
})

export class VimeoVideoComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('vimeoVideoContainer') vimeoVideoContainer;
  public player: Player;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.player = new Player(this.vimeoVideoContainer.nativeElement, {
        id: 19231868, // Generic Id
        width: 640
    });
  }

}
```

Where **vimeo-player.component.html**:

```
<div id="vimeoVideoContainer"></div>
```

And I'm trying to use it inside another template's component. For instance inside **my.component.ts**'s template I have:

```
<app-vimeo-video-player></app-vimeo-video-player>
```

I'm getting `Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined` even thought I managed to use `ngAfterViewInit`. Same thing happens if I set a timeout before triggering `new Player()...`.

I found this issue on [vimeo/player.js issues](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js/issues/144) but it didn't help me.

**EDIT 1**:

With @peinearydevelopment I solved this particular error but now I'm getting: `ERROR TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__vimeo_player__.Player is not a constructor`.

**What Am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your div to: `<div #vimeoVideoContainer></div>`

While I can't find great documentation, here is the ViewChild [documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildDecorator). There are a number of different places in their documentation where they use this with different selector types. As you can see from the documentation, it would accept a Type which doesn't seem applicable here as you aren't selecting a custom component. The above syntax is what I've seen most commonly when using a string to select an element.

About your second Edit, try importing `Player` as follows `import * as Player from '@vimeo/player/dist/player.js';`

Comment: Can you explain why? Anyways I get another error `StartNetworkComponent.html:2 ERROR TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__vimeo_player__.Player is not a constructor`.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to find the documentation to help explain.